# Jquery inline password field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a function to initialize all fields with a certain class to be inline labels. I have the obvious problem of password fields showing * instead of characters. I have almost overcome this problem, except somewhere down the line. When I switch between username and password, the values I stored to be replaced on blur or on focus are being lost. Here is the code I created so far. It is part of a function that is called at document ready.

```
$('.inlineLabel').focus(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("initial") === undefined) {
        $(this).attr("initial",$(this).val());
    }
    if ($(this).val() === $(this).attr("initial")) {
        $(this).val("");
    }
}).blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "") {
        $(this).val($(this).attr("initial"));
    }
});

var passwordElement = $('input#password').clone(true);

var label = $("<input type='text' />").attr({
    id: 'label',
    name: passwordElement.name,
    value: 'Password' });
passwordElement.blur(function() {
    $('input#password').replaceWith(label);
});

$(this).replaceWith(label);



label.focus(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith(passwordElement);
    console.log(passwordElement);
    $('input#password').focus();
});
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the `placeholder` html attribute?